# Preserving the index when selecting a slice of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

So I am creating my training and test sets for use in a Multiple Linear Regression model using sklearn.

my dataset contains 182 features looks like the following;

```
id      feature1 feature2  ....  feature182 Target
D24352  145      8               7          1
G09340  10       24              0          0
E40988  6        42              8          1
H42093  238      234             2          1   
F32093  12       72              1          0
```

I have then have the following code;

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\\mylocation\\myfile.csv')
dataset0 = dataset.set_index('t1.id')
dataset2 = pd.get_dummies(dataset0)
y = dataset0.iloc[:, 31:32].values
dataset2.pop('Target')
X = dataset2.iloc[:, :180].values
```

Once I use `dataframe.iloc` however, I loose my indexes (which I have set to be my IDs). I would like to keep these as I currently have no way of telling which records in my results relate to which records in my original `dataset` when I do the following step;

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `.values` for `y` and `X` definitions? Index *labels* are only meaningful for Pandas series, not NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is stored as `object` type. You should convert it to float64 (assuming that all your data is of numeric type. Else only convert those rows, that you want to have as numeric type). Since it turns out your index is of type string, you need to set the `dtype` of your dataframe **after** setting the index (and generating the dummies). Again assuming that the rest of your data is of numeric type:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\\mylocation\\myfile.csv')
dataset0 = dataset.set_index('t1.id')
dataset2 = pd.get_dummies(dataset0)
dataset0 = dataset0.astype(np.float64)  # add this line to explicitly set the dtype
```

Now you should be able to just leave out `values` when slicing the DataFrame:

```
y = dataset0.iloc[:, 31:32]
dataset2.pop('Target')
X = dataset2.iloc[:, :180]
```

With `.values` you access the underlying numpy arrays of the DataFrame. These do not have an index column. Since `sklearn` is, in most cases, compatible with `pandas`, you can simply pass a pandas DataFrame to sklearn.

If this does not work, you can still apply reset_index to your DataFrame. This will add the index as a new column, which you will have to drop when passing the training data to sklearn:

```
dataset0.reset_index(inplace=True)
dataset2.reset_index(inplace=True)
y = dataset0.iloc[:, 31:32].values
dataset2.pop('Target')
X = dataset2.iloc[:, :180].values

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train.drop('index', axis=1), y_train.drop('index', axis=1))

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test.drop('index', axis=1))
```

In this case you'll still have to change the slicing `[:, 31:32]` and `[:, :180]` to the correct columns, so that the index will be included in the slice.

Comment: Sorry bud but dropping the `.values` gave me an error that states `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [31] of <class 'int'>`, I was also unable to view the output `y_test` and `y_pred` in Spyder when running your second snippet getting an error telling me that `object arrays are not currently supported`

Comment: Sounds like your dataframe is not of a numeric type. Have you tried setting it to float64 explicitly? And what does your index look like? Is it an integer index? I added a few lines to my answer.

Comment: The indexes are not integer indexes, they are strings.

Comment: Honestly: It is quite hard to *guess* what your dataframe looks like. Could you please post a short sample of `dataset`? 5 rows is enough. And it was much easier, if you provided all information from the beginning. :) So your index is of type string. Are there any other rows which are not numeric?

Comment: Hi @Scotty1 I have added an example of the dataset. Also, when I run the code you have above, I get an error that reads `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100%'`.

Comment: Yes, that is a string value in your column. You need to convert that value if you want to have a float, since `'100%'` is not a valid numeric representation in python. Thanks for adding the sample dataset. Could you please add all relevant columns? Specifically those with non-numeric values are interesting/important.

Comment: I found some calculations that I had done in excel were screwing this up. I have it working now and have updated your answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer and nice that it is working! Just for your information: If you have to convert values of specific columns, let's say the percentage values of kind `'87.5%'` are in the column `'features123'`, you can specify the converter like this: `converters={'features123': lambda x: float(x[:-1])}` and pass this/these converter to pandas with `pd.read_csv(...., converters=converters)`. Oh and thanks for the suggested edit. I accepted it but left the last part in it, because it may be interesting for others with a similar problem.